OpenSSL python-flask API subdomain
I have an API service built on Python-Flask & hosted on a subdomain e.g. api.example.com,
I have installed OpenSSL ceritificate with CN (wildcard) as *.example.com
My react app is hosted on a domain example.com, but when I am tring to access https://wwww.example.com, it calls API which is giving an error ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID.
Looking for some help here
my nginx conf file is as
server {
                listen 443 ssl;
                ssl_certificate /home/ubuntu/ssl/cert.pem;
                ssl_certificate_key /home/ubuntu/ssl/key.pem;

                server_name example.com;
                
                access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
                error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
                
                ssl_session_timeout 10m;


                location / {
                include proxy_params;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5001;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "*";
                add_header Vary Origin; 

                
                }
            
            }


server {
            listen 443 ssl;
            server_name api.example.com;

                            
            ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
            ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;

            location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;               
                add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS";
                #add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Authorization, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept";
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';

                add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials 'true';

        
            }
        }

it wasnt really because of the nginx config and the main issue was the self signed certificate giving ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID error...

When a certificate is self-signed, the issued to and issued by fields are the same, indicating that the certificate was not issued by a recognized Certificate Authority (CA). Most browsers and clients do not trust self-signed certificates because they cannot verify the identity of the issuer.

Got the new valid certificate and everything worked like anything...
To get valid free wildcard certificate https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/wildcard-certificates-using-lets-encrypt-certbot-pallavi-udhane/
